# How to fetch value from a JSON having element "return"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a sample JSON

```
{"status":200,
"invocationContext":null,
"invocationResult":{"responseID":"13","statusCode":200},
"fetchXmlResponse":{"ns":"http://ws.src.com","return":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><TemplateData>data</TemplateData>"}
}
```

How to access "return" element from above object?

```
alert("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result.fetchXmlResponse.return));
```

above code throws error because of `return` keyword
Is there any other way to fetch (or access) `return` element's value?

Comment: Maybe `JSON.stringify(result.fetchXmlResponse["return"]))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alternative syntax:

```
alert("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result.fetchXmlResponse['return']));
```

Javascript objects are represented as hash maps, so any property can be acessed either as a member field, or via the square brackets. The latter approach can be used for members that are javascript keywords, or browser-specific constructs (like 'export' in some IE versions)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `return` property by name, though it's probably best to reformat your response so that it isn't using keywords for property names:

`alert("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result.fetchXmlResponse['return']));`

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
alert("Result: " +obj.fetchXmlResponse.return);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing it as if it was an array (psst. it is). Look at this example

http://jsfiddle.net/morph3y/svSth/

```
fetchXmlResponse['return']
```